# Excel to csv for machine learning, can't find columns

Tags: excel, pandas

I've collected some values, imported these from a text file into excel and was planning on using them for machine learning purposes (practice) and in Python. However, when I saved my file as a CSV file (which is required for the Auto-ML on Google Cloud) and tried to load it into pandas as a csv file as well as auto-ml, it doesn't display the values correct; in fact, all "headers" are simply clustered together; I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I want to use the following file I have in this case:

[download file here](https://tmpfiles.org/download/141831/allvalues.xlsx)

Not sure if I'm doing the headers wrong or why it doesn't work to display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the file to csv from any free online excel to csv converters rather than changing the file type to csv

Comment: I chose it as the "correct answer". Couldn't before as there is a time limit before I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding, or "what" is separating the values.